# Send a password to a user who has just registered for a member area

Tags: user-registration, password, members

Here I meet a little problem with my code.

#### What I do

Well I was largely inspired by a tutorial to make a registration system login to a member area under wordpress in the case of a theme developed.
However everything is functional because the user manages to sign up to disconnect etc.

#### What I want

However I would not ask him for the password when registering but only his [name, surname, and email]
Then when he validates I send him the password in the email address submitted during registration.
My question is, can we do it with wordpress if so how?
Else is what we do the classic system like password request during registration and then prevent him from logging on before confirming his email. Thank you

#### What I get

For now I have no issue because I do not know any way to achieve what I want.

I hope I have been clear, sometimes!

Comment: There are several [articles](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-moderate-new-user-registrations-in-wordpress/) [and](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/) [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-verification/) that seem to handle this kind of thing. Do none of those fit your situation, and if not, can you be more specific to what you're looking for?

Comment: Most of articles in the web is about using plugins. But i have develop a specific theme. So i'am looking for a developed solution.